# CSS3 transform applied from JS does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

In my Android Hybrid app which uses Crosswalk need to apply a CSS3 transform to an HTML element at run time.  I thought this was a relatively trival task but found that it simply would not work.  Initially I suspected that this was down to a missing capability in the Crosswalk/Chromium implementation of the spec.  However, to be safe I much the same thing in my desktop Chrome browser as shown below

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', transIt);

function transIt() {
  alert('Transforming now!');
  var blobStyle = document.getElementById('blob').style;
  blobStyle.webkitTransform = 'translate(100px,50px);';
  blobStyle.webkitTransform = 'translate(100px,50px);';
  alert('Did it work?');
}
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
}

#blob {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
  top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='blob'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<button id='btn'>Transform It</button>
```

Much to my surprise this relatively simple code does not deliver the intended results in Chrome on Windows either.  Either I am doing something wrong here that I am unable to spot or else there are other underlying issues at work.  Perhaps someone here might have an insight that I do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set prefixed [CSS styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) properties, use `cssText`.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', transIt);

function transIt() {
  document.getElementById('blob').style.cssText = '-webkit-transform: translate(100px,50px); transform: translate(100px,50px);';
}
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
}

#blob {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
  top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='blob'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<button id='btn'>Transform It</button>
```

---

Or `setAttribute()`

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', transIt);

function transIt() {
  document.getElementById('blob').setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform: translate(100px,50px); transform: translate(100px,50px);');
}
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
}

#blob {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
  top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='blob'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<button id='btn'>Transform It</button>
```

---

Update based on a comment

If you already set styles inline, like in this sample where the inline style set the background to red, you need to append the new CSS.

*Note, make sure you have a semicolon `;` at the beginning of the `newCSS` string, so the properties are properly separated*

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', transIt);

function transIt() {
  var newCSS = ';-webkit-transform: translate(100px,50px); transform: translate(100px,50px)'
  document.getElementById('blob').style.cssText += newCSS;
}
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
}

#blob {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
  top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='blob' style="background: red;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<button id='btn'>Transform It</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have subsequently "unaccepted" this answer since although it works on Chrome/Windows the issue is not resolved in Crosswalk/Chromium where attempting to set CSS text simply annuls any other styling already applied to the element.

Comment: @DroidOS Updated with a second sample using `setAttribute()` ... does that work?

Comment: @DroidOS Updated with a 3rd sample

Comment: Thank you.  I decided to accept your answer since in all fairness you have given a complete answer to my original question.  The fact that are issues with Crosswalk/Chromium is another matter altogether. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

- The semi-colon (`;`) in CSS is used to separate `property:value` pairs. It is not part of the value.
- Vendor prefixed properties are used for *experimental* features. They should not be used in production. My browser no longer supports `webkitTransform` because `transform` has been stable for ages.

Remove the `;` from the values and use the `transform` property instead.

```
  blobStyle.transform = 'translate(100px,50px)';
```

You also only need to set the value *once*.

NB: It is generally better to define these things in a stylesheet and toggle class names instead.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', transIt);

function transIt() {
  alert('Transforming now!');
  var blobStyle = document.getElementById('blob').style;
  blobStyle.transform = 'translate(100px,50px)';
  alert('Did it work?');
}
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
}

#blob {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
  top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='blob'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<button id='btn'>Transform It</button>
```

Comment: It was the semicolon for me indeed...